# Google App Script (HTMLService)/Jquery <Select> Removing Spaces?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, space

I have a WebApp that I'm developing using GAS (HTMLService) -- I've got some jQuery in there but I'm not sure that matters.

Long story short I have several  elements in my WebApp --- when I `doPost` the results from these drop down lists I find that my data is corrupt -- I'm missing anything after a space.

For Example:

```
(602) 555-1212 becomes     (602)
San Antonio becomes         San
```

I've tried Googling the answer for myself but I've come up with nothing...I am going to assume Caja is causing this issue -- I'm hopeful someone out there has a workaround.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What does your doPost contain. Please post some code. It is impossible to give you an answer with the current level of information provided

Comment: Thanks for your response...I was able to figure it out after a night of sleep.

Comment: UPDATE: Thank you for your quick replies. As it turns out I was making a very basic error --- missing quotation marks around the variable name. 

It was a simple fix after a night of sleeping. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple case of missing quotation marks.

```
var x = '<select><option value=$('#blah').val()>$('#blah').val()</option>';
```

should have been:

```
var x = "<select><option value='$('#blah').val()'>$('#blah').val()</option>";
```

Then it works great!